# ImageButton OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, kotlin, imagebutton

So I have the following ImageButton in a fragment:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/moneyBtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/monkey"
            android:background="@null"/>
```

And the following fragmentActivity.kt

```
class Home : Fragment()  {

    override public fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val moneyButton: ImageButton = view?.findViewById(R.id.moneyBtn) as ImageButton


        val result = MyAppApplication()
        var money = result.money

        moneyButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })


        return view
    }
```

I also tried to use the "normal" Kotline setOnClickListener

```
moneyButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

The App dosent crash and dosent freeze, it just dont work

I also tried to replace the Toast with a throw, but that wont be exceuted either.
Maybe you can find my mistake?

Comment: Do you mind posting up the Activity class that opens up the fragment?

Comment: I haven't any reason for think that method run in other thread that UI, but I can't find any reason. Try to run your Toast in UI thread using `runOnUiThread`

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your click listener in `onActivityCreated`. It's called after `onCreateView` so it'll ensure that `view` is inflated.

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val moneyButton: ImageButton = activity.findViewById(R.id.moneyBtn) as ImageButton
    moneyButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: it's in a fragment :/

Comment: @Foose It's possible to get view elements by calling `activity.findViewById(resId)` in your `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and it can be done like following codes:

In your `Fragment`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

            val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
            val imgViewButton = rootView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.moneyBtn) // Use the current view

            imgViewButton?.setOnClickListener() {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }


        return rootView
  }
```

The reason is the `View` which we weren't get it in the right way. But, with these codes, it sets the current `View` and then after all, returns the view which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you even know that this code is executed? That the listener is set? Maybe try to use the **Log class** (should be the same in Kotlin as in Java).
Also,

```
val result = MyAppApplication()
var money = result.money
```

looks suspicious to me. Are you trying to create a new Application instance?

Comment: yes, everything else works fine, the log confirms that :/ I'm using the Application Inst to store "global" variables, that works fine too. Deleting this code doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I just tried your code snippets on my platform, and the Toast pops up just fine... Try changing the first arg of Toast to view.context instead so it'd look something like:

```
Toast.makeText(view.context, "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Let me know if that makes a difference.